# Spring model attributes access from Angular MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

For may Webapplication project I have this controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="main", method=RequestMethod.GET)    
    public String main(Model m){
    ....    
    m.addAttribute("isAdmin", cm.CheckUserIsAdmin().toString()));
        return "main";
    }
```

This attribute is accessible from the main.jsp file via

```
<c:if test="${isAdmin}">
```

I use Angular with MVC model and when I use the same command in a partial page (set by ng-view in the main.jsp) it is not resolvable. So the question is how to access `isAdmin` variable from controller for a specific view?

Comment: In terms of angular methodology what you are asking doesn't really make sense

Comment: In other words I have to access `isAdmin` variable  set by Spring Controller from the Angular controller for a specific view

Comment: You should be making request to back end using angular `$http`

Comment: so just send a rest request to the server?

Comment: Why are you using angular and jsp views together????

Comment: jsp was good to check this variable on the main page, for the rest angular